# What's the joke in Dom's words?

Tags: jokes, pun

At beach party in *Fast X* (2023), Isabel says to Dom, who is expert in car racing:

> Isabel: It would have felt good to beat him
>
> Dom: You and everyone here.

*(people laughs)*

What's the joke in Dom's words?

Comment: Not only Isabel, but everyone else there would have been glad to beat 'him', whoever 'he' is. The laughter is probably because Dom's remark is considered to be witty.

Comment: Everybody laughs because they know they'll probably get another 10 movies out of this terrible franchise.

Comment: @Astralbee I am pretty sure they are not breaking the forth wall like you said.

Comment: @Astralbee Probably not what they meant, but I laughed!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey witty how ?

Comment: CameronMelvin - see answer by @acme_54 below.

Comment: I've not seen the movie, but a perfectly credible explanation for the laughter might simply be that everyone dislikes whoever Isabel just failed to beat, but *Isabel was one of their best chances to beat the guy*. In which case the laughter may be laced with  "irony" because if even ***she*** couldn't beat him, the others have next to no chance - but shared laughter helps to "bond" the assembled company who all have to ruefully accept that (barring a miracle) they're never gonna get to even ***see someone else*** beat the "unwelcome winner", let alone beat him themselves.

Comment: This isn't a question about learning English. If you ask on Movies and TV Stack Exchange people who know the film may be able to tell you what's going on, based on characters' histories and the events of the movie.

Answer (score -1):

The joke is a play on words about the 2 meanings of "beat"-
1.- To win against someone, eg in a race;
2.- To hit (beat up) someone.

Comment: Why don't you think it has the normal meaning that everyone here would have enjoyed beating him in a race?

Comment: What @gotube said. If there was wordplay involving ***to beat up = physically attack and injure***, the scriptwriters would have had Dom reply with something like *"**Up**, you mean. Yeah, we'd all like to do that*.